# How do I add this option to this image-picker project?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. The concept is that I have 4 clickable image created by this http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ and I want to create option that will forward somebody to appropriate href link after clicking button and choosing appropiate image. For instance if I would click image with cat and then button, it will forward me to page about cats. If I would click image with dog and button, it will forward me to page about dogs, if I would click images with dog and cat and button, it will forward me to page about dogs and cats.

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<script src="js.js"></script>



<!-- scripts for imagepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="image-picker.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>


<!--code for imagepicker-->
<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html">
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" href="http://cats.com" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" href="http://dogs.com" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" href="http://dogsandcats.com" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>

</select>

<button href="#">Forward</button>


<script>

$("select").imagepicker()

</script>
</body>


</html>
```

How do I do this? I completely don't have any idea :/.

Comment: You'l need to write a script that checks to see which options are selected when the user clicks a button, and then depending on which are selected, redirect them to the appropriate website.

Comment: Yeah, How do I do this?

Comment: I guess for starters, you'd probably want to learn Javascript and/or jQuery! Stack Overflow usually functions to help people debug problems they're having with code *they've already written*, rather than to write your code *for* you. :P

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if this works. I added a script which, when you change your choice, changes the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<script src="js.js"></script>



<!-- scripts for imagepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="image-picker.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="image-picker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        //wait for the page to be fully loaded
        window.onload = function() {
            initialize();
        }
    </script>



</head>
<body>


<!--code for imagepicker-->
<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html" id="selectImg">
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="http://cats.com">Cute Kitten 1</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="http://dogs.com">Cute Kitten 2</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="http://dogsandcats.com">Cute Kitten 3</option>

</select>

<button href="#" id="forwardButton">Forward</button>

<script>

function initialize() {

    var choice = document.getElementById("selectImg").value;

    //changes destination when you set or change your choice
    document.getElementById("selectImg").onchange = function() {
        choice = document.getElementById("selectImg").value;
    }

    //when button is clicked
    document.getElementById("forwardButton").onclick = function() {
        if (choice !== ("" || "undefined")) {
            window.location = choice;
        }       
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```